# Critical region codes and Semaphores

Tags: semaphore, critical-section

The semaphores ,which are data structure created by the operating system, are used for providing a synchronization and creating mutual exclusion between the processes. wait() and signal() are methods which are invoked by the operating system in order to manage the semaphores and these methods cannot be interrupted by interrupt service routine signals.

What I am wondering is whether critical region codes between wait() and signal() methods can be interrupted or not ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes they can be interrupted simply because the definition itself **proposes no such restriction**.

In concurrent programming, concurrent accesses to shared resources can lead to unexpected or erroneous behavior, so parts of the program where the shared resource is accessed are protected. This protected section is the critical section or critical region. It cannot be executed by more than one process at a time.

So critical-section demands **mutual exclusion** but it does not say anything about **atomicity**.

So Yes, critical region codes between wait() and signal() methods can be interrupted but a good synchronization construct would be that once a process/thread enters critical section, even if that process later is interrupted, no other process would be able to enter critical section.